# I can't find the error on my program (C++)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void divider();

int main()
{
    int cstats, choice;
    int rhp, hp, atk, def, matk, mdef, dmg, mdmg, agi, magi;
    divider();
    cout << "Kill the Zombie! (Text-Based Game)\n";
    divider();
    cout << "Please choose your specialty: ";
    cout << "[1] Offense [2] Magic [3] Defense [4] Speed\n";
    do{cin >> cstats; }
    while(cstats > 4 || cstats < 1);
    {
    switch(cstats)
    {
    case 1:
        atk = 15;
        def = 8;
        agi = 6;
        matk = 5;
        mdef = 5;
        magi = 5;
        break;
    case 2:
        atk = 5;
        def = 5;
        agi = 5;
        matk = 15;
        mdef = 7;
        magi = 6;
        break;
    case 3:
        atk = 7;
        def = 15;
        agi = 5;
        matk = 1;
        mdef = 14;
        magi = 3;
        break;
    case 4:
        atk = 7;
        def = 4;
        agi = 15;
        matk = 3;
        mdef = 4;
        magi = 14;
        break;
    }
    if(cstats == 1)
    {
    cout << "You have chosen Offense\n";
    }
    if(cstats == 2)
    {
    cout << "You have chosen Magic\n";
    }
    if(cstats == 3)
    {
    cout << "You have chosen Defense\n";
    }
    if(cstats == 4)
    {
    cout << "You have chosen Speed\n";
    }
    }
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    rhp = rand()%500 + 200;
    hp = rand()%500 + 200;
    while(hp > 0 || rhp > 0 )
    {
    cout << "What do you want to do? [1] Normal Attack [2] Magic Attack [3] Defend [4] Dodge\n";
    do{cin >> choice; }
    while(choice > 4 || choice < 1);
    {
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            atk = rand()%20+10;
            break;
        case 2:
            matk = rand()%20+10;
            break;
        case 3:
            atk = rand()%5+1;
            def = rand()%10+10;
            break;
        case 4:
            agi = rand()%10+10;
            break;
    }
    if(choice == 1)
    {
    mdmg = ((0.10 * def) / (1 + 0.10 * def)) * 100;
    }
    if(choice == 2)
    {
    mdmg = ((0.20 * mdef) / (1 + 0.20 * mdef)) * 100;
    }
    if(choice == 3)
    {
    dmg = ((0.06 * def) / (1 + 0.06 * def)) * 100;
    }
    if(choice == 4)
    {
    mdmg = ((0.10 * agi) / (1 + 0.20 * agi)) * 100;
    }
    rhp = rhp - mdmg;
    cout << "You did " << mdmg << "damage to the zombie!\n";
    cin.get();
    if(rhp <1)
    {
        cout << "You killed the Zombie! Congratulations, You won with " << hp << "hp left.\n";
        cin.get();
        system("pause>0");
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "The Zombie now has " << rhp << "hp left.\n";
    dmg = ((0.06 * def) / (1 + 0.06 * def)) * 100;
    dmg = ((0.10 * mdef) / (1 + 0.10 * mdef)) * 100;
    dmg = ((0.05 * agi) / (1 + 0.05 * agi)) * 100;
    if(dmg < 0)
    {
        dmg = 0;
    }
    hp = hp - dmg;
    cout << "The Zombie hit you for " << dmg << " damage.\n";
    if(hp < 1 )
    {
        cout << "You died. The Zombie still has " << rhp << "hp left.\n";
        cin.get();
        system("pause>0");
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "You now have " << hp << " hp left.\n";
}
}
}
void divider()
{
    cout << "*************************************\n";
}
```

This is the whole code of my program and I always get an error saying "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'mdmg' is being used without being initialized." Where did I go wrong? I can't find it. I need to finish this in 3 hours. :(

Comment: Looks like a typo in your choice == 3 branch where you typed dmg instead of mdmg. Also, look into the switch statement as an alternative to a sequence of if statements checking the same variable.

Comment: Get cozy with the debugger.

Comment: Error message is very clear: initialize 'mgmg' prior to if-else statements.

Comment: @P0W `do { ... } while(...);`, but I'm guessing the logic may not be what they think it is...

Comment: Thank you P0W! It is Fixed now! :D

Comment: I can't find the error because my eyes are sleepy. :D Thanks again :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your issue is here:

```
if(choice == 3)
{
dmg = ((0.06 * def) / (1 + 0.06 * def)) * 100;
    rhp = rhp - mdmg;
}
```

If you call that before any other choices, mdmg won't be initialized before being subtracted from rhp.

EDIT:

Although taking the second statement out is a good idea, you still have the same issue that mdmg is not initialized in the `if(choice ==3)` block.  Did you mean to write

```
if(choice == 3)
{
    mdmg = ((0.06 * def) / (1 + 0.06 * def)) * 100;
}
```

(dmg is changed to mdmg)

Comment: I have now changed it but I still got error
if(choice == 3)
 {
 dmg = ((0.06 * def) / (1 + 0.06 * def)) * 100;
 }
 if(choice == 4)
 {
 mdmg = ((0.10 * agi) / (1 + 0.20 * agi)) * 100;
 }
 rhp = rhp - mdmg;

Comment: Looking at the surrounding code `dmg` should be replaced with `mdmg`.

Comment: Issues is here:      `cout << "You did " << mdmg << "damage to the zombie!\n";`     outside the if (or switch statements). The value of mdmg remains uninitialized if not initialized in any one of the branches.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you try to use `mdmg` without initializing it as the error tells you.

`cout << "You did " << mdmg << "damage to the zombie!\n";`

You assign values to `mdmg` in your various `if` statements, but since there is not a default value for `mdmg` (there is the chance you may not enter one of the `if` blocks that assigns a value to `mdmg`), you get an error when trying to print it out.

Either intialize it when you declare it (`int mdmg = 0;`) or have some other means not inside one of the `if` statements to assign a default value.